# Not able to parse time properly

Tags: go

I'm trying to parse time for values in a template like so:

```
"parseDate": func(timeStamp time.Time) string {
            newTime, err := time.Parse("Jan 2 2006 @ 15:04:05", fmt.Sprintf("%v", timeStamp))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            return fmt.Sprintf("%v", newTime)
},
```

which is one of my handler funcs, but I get this error:

`parsing time "2015-12-13 06:49:52 +0000 UTC" as "Jan 2 2006 @ 15:04:05": cannot parse "2015-12-13 06:49:52 +0000 UTC" as "Jan"`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Why on earth do you want to **re**-parse the time after printing it with fmt.Sprintf? The whole code is completely pointless.

Comment: @Volker the intention was to get it into the format of `2015-12-13 @ 05:06:06` which I though I would have to parse it into a string so I could call parse on it, maybe I'm just confused who knows

Comment: Yes that is a confusion. time.Time --> string is done with the time.Format() method (https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) and *not* with fmt.Sprintf. There is zero need to parse a string if you want to format a time as a string.

Comment: What is your input format? I am confused by the double timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse it as

```
t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST")
```

For parsing you have to give the format of the date you are receiving.

Then you can format the correctly parsed time using

```
t.Format("Jan 2 2006 @ 15:04:05")
```